# DB2 - Using Running totals to calculate Month To Date Sales

Tags: sql, db2, cumulative-sum

I'm calculating the Month to date sales using DB2 code to compare July 2019 vs July 2018 totals.

It needs to be rolling to compare the current month of data to the same month last year, otherwise I am comparing two different periods of data.

EG if it were static, I'd be comparing mtd July (2019) week 2 sales vs mtd July week 4 (2018).

I need mtd July 2019 week 2 vs mtd July (2018) week 2 mtd Sales.

**How can I get MTD Rolling sales in DB2??**

I've tried a static MTD - Which is ; however, this is not the ideal method. For rolling, I've tried a sum() over but this returns a syntax error (-119 & -727).

Sample table

> ### Year |Month | Week | Sales
>
> 2018 | July | 1 | 2000
>
> 2018 | July | 2 | 1500
>
> 2018 | July | 3 | 1000
>
> 2018 | July | 4 | 2000
>
> 2019 | July | 1 | 1750
>
> 2019 | July | 2 | 2100

Expected Results

> Year |Month | Week | Sales | Running Total
>
> ---
>
> 2018 | July | 1 | 2000 | 2000
>
> 2018 | July | 2 | 1500 | 3500
>
> 2018 | July | 3 | 1000 | 4500
>
> 2018 | July | 4 | 2000 | 6500
>
> 2019 | July | 1 | 1750 | 1750
>
> 2019 | July | 2 | 2100 | 3850

-- Incorrect results gathered from static

> Year |Month | Week | Sales | Running Total
>
> ---
>
> 2018 | July | 1 | 2000 | 6500
>
> 2018 | July | 2 | 1500 | 6500
>
> 2018 | July | 3 | 1000 | 6500
>
> 2018 | July | 4 | 2000 | 6500
>
> 2019 | July | 1 | 1750 | 3850
>
> 2019 | July | 2 | 2100 | 3850

Code from Static (works but incorrect for comparing current month):

```
Select
     a.Year,
     a.Month,
     a.Week,
     sum(a.sales) as weekly
     mtd.mtd_sales as MTD
from sales a 
inner join 
     (Select
          a.Year,
          a.Month,
          sum(a.sales) as mtd_sales
      from sales a
      group by
          a.Year,
          a.Month) MTD on MTD.week = a.week
group by
     a.Year,
     a.Month,
     a.Week,
     mtd.mtd;
```

I've tried using the below code for rolling, but it produces error (SQL State -119 & - 727) which I believe indicates a syntax error.

Code for rolling

```
Select
  a.Year,
  a.Month,
  a.Week,
  sum(a.sales) over (Partition by week order by 
month) 
from sales a
group by
    a.year,
    a.month,
    a.week;
```

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?

Comment: Is there an easy way to check in SQuirreL SQL client to verify what version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply run the window function, `SUM() OVER()`, at original row level and not inside an aggregate query. Additionally, adjust the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses as your groupings should be *year* and *month* and *week* should be the ordering column.

```
SELECT
  s.Year,
  s.Month,
  s.Week,
  s.Sales,
  SUM(s.sales) over (PARTITION BY s.Year, s.Month ORDER BY s.Week) as running_total
FROM sales s;
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=7c81272a7098a0f268b71cdb50e3fd51) *(using Db2 Developer-C 11.1 version)*